# Angular 4 - limit HTTP request to one every 200 milliseconds while filtering

Tags: angular, typescript, http, rxjs, angular-pipe

I'm working on a project where I have a page that has an `ngFor` displaying an array of objects. I want to give the user the ability to filter those objects by typing in certain keywords in an input field.

The filtering of the data has to be done server side, so I implemented a call for this in my service.

```
public searchProperties(query: string): Observable<IProperty[]> {
    console.log('SERVICE: query: ' + query);
    let params = new HttpParams();

    params = params.append('q', query);

    return this.http.get<IProperty[]>(this.baseUrl+'/api/property', {params: params})
    .do( response => {
      console.log('Successfully retrieved the search response');
    }).catch((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
      console.log('Something went wrong while retrieving the search response');
      return Observable.throw(error);
    })
  }
```

I call this method in a pipe like this:

```
  transform(items: IProperty[], searchText: string): any[] {
    if(!items) return [];
    if(!searchText) return items;

    console.log('PIPE: Amount of items in items array BEFORE: ' + items.length);

    this.propertyService.searchProperties(searchText).subscribe(
      result => {
        items = result;
      }, error => {
        console.log('Failed to retrieve the properties that were searched for');
        return items;
      },
      () => {
        console.log('PIPE: Amount of items in items array AFTER: ' + items.length);
        return items;
      }
    )
  }
```

I added the pipe to my ngFor in the html like this:

```
 <div class="col-md-4" *ngFor="let property of properties | property_filter : searchText ; let i=index">
```

There are two problems with my current code:

1. Whenever I type some keyword in the input field, the http call does get called and returns a response to the pipe, but my page shows no objects, the ngFor just remains empty until I clear the input field again.
2. While typing, the HTTP call should only be fired off every 200 milliseconds instead of on every single change event.

Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE:**

I removed the pipe and implemented the call in the component. The list of objects is now properly updated.

The only question that still remains is how can I limit the amount of responses to one every 200 milliseconds?

Comment: are you reimplementing `autocomplete`? look this package https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-auto-complete

Comment: if you are passing property array than why you are filter again using service in you pipe transform code ???

Comment: seems you are trying to use pipe wrong way

Comment: I tried it without a pipe by just calling the service in the component but even with the two way binding the view wasn't updated

Comment: I no longer use a pipe now, you can look at the updated question.

Comment: updated my answer have a look ....you have to use debounceTime function for limiting http request ...please do accept/upvote if you got infor you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for firing event after your change after certain second you make use of [`debounceTime`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/filtering/debouncetime.html) function of RxJs as below.

```
<input type="text" [ngModel]="term" (ngModelChange)="change($event)"/>

import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
import { Component }   from '@angular/core';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/debounceTime';

export class AppComponent{
    term: string;
    modelChanged: Subject<string> = new Subject<string>();

    constructor() {
        this.modelChanged
       .debounceTime(300) // wait 300ms after the last event before emitting last event
       .distinctUntilChanged() // only emit if value is different from previous value
       .subscribe(model => this.model = model);
    }

    change(text: string) {
        this.modelChanged.next(text);
       //code for filtering goes here 
    }
}


____
```

---

Following is code of mine which I used for filtering Email addresses coming from server and it working fine

Pipe.ts

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { ReportService } from './ReportService';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Pipe({
  name: 'filter'
})

export class MyFilter implements PipeTransform {
  emails: Array<string>= new Array<string>();
  constructor(private reportservice :ReportService)
  {}

    transform(items: any[], term: string): any {
      debugger;
      if (!term) 
        return items;
       this.reportservice.GetAllEmails().subscribe(e=> this.emails = e);
       return this.emails.filter(item => item.indexOf(term) > -1);
    }
}
```

App.Component.Html

```
<form id="filter">
  <label>Searching for email</label>
  <input type="text" name="termtext" [(ngModel)]="term" />
</form>

<ul *ngFor="let email of emails| filter:term">
    {{email}}
</ul>
```

App.component.ts

```
  term:string;
  emails: Array<string> = new Array<string>();
  constructor()
  {
    this.term="test";
  }
```

First time it take time as its fetching data from serve but it working form next time fine.

Comment: Whenever I type a value in the input all the calls are delayed and fired off at the same time after the supplied time.

Comment: @DennisN - that is have debounceTime works , it send all input value at once at predefined time ...what you want ?

Comment: I actually would prefer that only one gets fired. I have an input field and now every time you type a letter in the input, a request is sent. I need the component to wait 200ms after each key down event so that there aren't that much requests sent while typing, but only the most recent one

Comment: @DennisN - that is what debounce function do it will sent request after every 300 ms in this case ...if there is no change in input it will not send request ...have you tried code ...

Comment: @DennisN - what if you type more they one key stock ...for example 5 key stock ...that means it wait for 100 ms that is what you want...debouncetime function designed for requirement like this only...have look to Rxjs

Comment: debounceTime is exactly what I need, I read the docs and tried to implement it. It waits to fire off the code, but for some weird reason it emits the same value multiple times. I will try to debug it.